# Checkbox Table VALUE , NAME and ID in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have a table of checkbox and i want to save them in my database, I need to save them eachone with its name and its value and in each one as a recorde :

```
 <tr><td><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" id="feat1"/>test1 </td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat9"/>test2 Monats </td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat17"/>test3m</td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat25"/>test4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="visible-xs" aria-hidden="true">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td> <input class="perm" name="feature[]"  type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat2"/>test5</td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat10"/>test6n</td>
    <td><input  class="perm" name="feature[]"  type="checkbox"  value="1" id="feat18"/>test7</td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox"  value="1" id="test8</td>
</tr>
```

and my PHP Code:

```
$checkBox[] =  implode(',',$_GET['feature']);


for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox ); $i++){

$tsql="INSERT INTO [dbo].[_PARAM](Value) VALUES ('" . $checkBox[$i] . "')";     

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
}
```

But my Database has 2 columns  **Name , Value**, ex. if the test1 and test2 checked

and I need the table to be like

```
Name      Value
```

---

```
test1      1
test2      1
test3     null
test4     null
 .....    ....
```

I need all the test and only the value 1 for the checked ones.

Comment: test1 , test2 are the values? if yes than why are u using 1, 1, 1, ?

Comment: @devpro  no they are the names , they could be anything else and i just need the to know if the checkbox checked or not so it could be 1 or X or anything else

Comment: and checkbox is fixed? always static?

Comment: @G.Margaritis ya it works but in the database i get not only the 1 value also the 0 of selected checkbox. so each checked box has 2 values first is 1 that it is checked an the other one is the hidden value 0 .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the values otherwise $_GET['feature'] will return an array of 1's

```
 <tr><td><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" id="feat1"/>test1 </td>
<td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="2"  id="feat9"/>test2 Monats </td>
<td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="3"  id="feat17"/>test3m</td>
<td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="4"  id="feat25"/>test4</td>
```

EDIT

```
input type=hidden value="1,2,3,4,..,n" name="available">
```

than in php

```
    $available=explode($_GET['available']); 
   foreach($available as $element) { 
   $values[$element]=in_array($element,$_GET['feature']) ? 1 : 0; 
   }
```

Comment: I need the value to be one if the checkbox checked

Comment: if you need to save 1 and 0 in the db for all the options than you need to also send all the options in an hidden element like: 
<input type="hidden" value="1,2,3,4,..,n" name="available"> 
and than in php do something like :
$available=explode($_GET['available']);
foreach($available as $element)
{
$values[$element]=in_array($element,$_GET['feature']) ? 1 : 0;
}
than insert based on values

Answer (score 0):

Keep a hidden field for every checkbox with value '0' (zero) like this:

```
<tr><td><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" id="feat1"/>test1 </td>
<td><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="hidden" value="0" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat9"/>test2 Monats </td>
<td><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="hidden" value="0" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat17"/>test3m</td>
<td><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="hidden" value="0" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="feat25"/>test4</td>
```

```
$checkBox[] =  implode(',',$_GET['feature']);

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox ); $i++){
    if ($checkBox[$i] == 0) {
        $checkBox[$i] = null;
    }
 $name = "test".($i+1);
$tsql="INSERT INTO [dbo].[_PARAM](Name, Value) VALUES ('".$name."', '" . $checkBox[$i] . "')";     

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox static than you can use an array which consist on checkbox values.

**Example:**

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
 <tr><td><input class="perm"  name="feature[]"  type="checkbox" value="test1" id="feat1"/>test1</td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="test2"  id="feat9"/>test2</td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="test3"  id="feat17"/>test3</td>
    <td><input  class="perm"  name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="test4"  id="feat25"/>test4</td>
</tr>
<input type="submit" name="submti">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submti'])){
    // all checkbox values
    $checkboxArr = array('test1','test2','test3','test4');

    if(is_array($_POST['feature'])){
        foreach ($checkboxArr as $value) {
            // check if value exist in post
            if(in_array($value, $_POST['feature'])){
                $newArr[$value] = 1; // if exist
            }
            else{
                $newArr[$value] = 0; // if not exist
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newArr);
}
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => 1
    [test2] => 1
    [test3] => 0
    [test4] => 0
)
```

Now you can use this array into your query as you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set the content of your td element (e.g. test1, test2)  as the value of the checkbox.You will also need a hidden input field for each checkbox and an indicator in the value field (0 or 1) about wether the checkbox is selected or not which is going to be prefix to the rest of the value attribute. When a checkbox is not checked,the form will pass as a value the one of the hidden field,wheras when the checkbox is checked, the form will pass as value the value of the checkbox, overwriting the value of the hidden field.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="feature[0]" value="0test1" /><input class="perm"  name="feature[0]"  type="checkbox" value="1test1" id="feat1"/>test1 </td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="feature[1]" value="0test2  Monats" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[1]" type="checkbox" value="1test2 Monats"  id="feat9"/>test2 Monats </td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="feature[2]" value="0test3m" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[2]" type="checkbox" value="1test3m"  id="feat17"/>test3m</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="feature[3]" value="0test4" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[3]" type="checkbox" value="1test4"  id="feat25"/>test4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="visible-xs" aria-hidden="true">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="feature[4]" value="0test5" /><input class="perm" name="feature[4]"  type="checkbox" value="1test5"  id="feat2"/>test5</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="feature[5]" value="0test6n" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[5]" type="checkbox" value="1test6n"  id="feat10"/>test6n</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="feature[6]" value="0test7" /><input  class="perm" name="feature[6]"  type="checkbox"  value="1test7" id="feat18"/>test7</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="feature[7]" value="0test8" /><input  class="perm"  name="feature[7]" type="checkbox"  value="1test8" id="feat8"/>test8</td>
</tr>
```

And your php code should look like this:

```
foreach($_GET["feature"] as $field)
{
    $name = substr($field, 1);
    $value = substr($field, 0,1) == 1 ? 1 : null;
    $tsql="INSERT INTO [dbo].[_PARAM](Name,Value) VALUES ('$name','$value')";     
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
}
```